# Fitting data to a square lattice (discrete points by multiple parameters)

Tags: least-squares, data-fitting

I have measured points on a two dimensional square lattice.

[image: data points].

How can I fit the data to a square lattice? I guess some methods like curve fitting or least square approximation would work, but I couldn't find any literature for the same problem.

- the lattice has discrete points
- the lattice is modeled with multiple parameters: translation (`x0` and `y0`), rotation (`θ`), lattice spacing (`d`), and it cannot be represented as `y=f(x; a,b,...)` form.

Comment: What do mean by "fit the data to a square lattice"? Do you mean you want to fit the data (interpolate or approximate) with a squared domain so that you can find the values at the lattice grid points?

Comment: I want to get parameters of the equation of a lattice: x0, y0, θ, and d.

Comment: @Hiro Did you get your problem solved? Recently I have exactly the same question which I asked today [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427598/lattice-fitting-regression?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; not possible (without punishment for fine lattices)

So I had the same question and I researched why it isn't possible. I show that for every `n` rational points, `x1, ... , xn` there exists some rational `q, b` such that for every `i` there exists an integer `z` such that `xi = z * q + b`.

## Proof by induction:

### base case:

We start at `n=2`, for that, choose `q = x1 - x0` and `b = x0`

### assumption:

let there be `x1, ..., xn+1` rational points. Then for the first `n` points, there exists some rational `q, b` such that for every `i<=n` there exists an integer `z` such that `xi = z * q + b`

### inductive step:

take `q, b` from the assumption. We find a natural number beta such that `q' := q / s, b` satisfies the assumption for `i<=n+1`.

Indeed, for every natural number and `i<=n`, when `xi = z * q + b`, then also `xi = z * s * q' + b`

Now we have to choose a natural `s`, such that `x := xn+1 = z * q' + b` for an integer `z`.

I will derive `s` and it will also be a proof that such a `s` exists. Define `beta` through `x = beta * q + b`. Because every number except `beta` is rational, so is `beta`:

`beta = u / v`

define `s := v`

Then it holds:
`x = beta * q + b = u / v * q + b = u / v * s * q' + b = u * q' + b`
where `u` is an integer.

### Empirical Proof

using the formulas from the proof, I made a python program that finds for arbitrary fractions the perfect lattice:

```py
from fractions import Fraction
import random

def random_fract():
    return Fraction(
        random.randint(2, 1_000),
        random.randint(2, 100)
    )

def test_one_lattice():
    x_vals = [random_fract() for i in range(1_000)]
    # remove duplicates -- the algorithm doesn't work for them
    x_vals = list(set(x_vals))
    q = x_vals[1] - x_vals[0]

    b = x_vals[0]
    for fract in x_vals[2:]:
        q /= ((fract-b) / q).denominator
    for x in x_vals:
        z = (x - b) / q
        assert z * q + b == x
        assert z % 1 == 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for _ in range(50):
        test_one_lattice()
```

keep in mind this also holds for multiple dimensions of the space (they are independent) and also for multiple dimensions of the lattice (just set the other vectors to zero)